# Rails Devise sign up form undefined method `devise_error_messages!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

i'm trying to use devise for handling user login/registration/forgotten password

I want to have sign up form at my root url root 'home#index'

**HomeController**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

    include DeviseHelper

    def index

    end

end
```

**DeviceHelper**

```
module DeviseHelper
    def resource_name
       :user
     end

     def resource_class 
        User 
     end

     def resource
       @resource ||= User.new
     end

     def devise_mapping
       @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
     end

end
```

**views/home/index.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name))  do |f| %>

<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <% if @minimum_password_length %>
  <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
  <% end %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
</div>
```

when I try to sign up with wrong attributes it shows me this error

> undefined method `devise_error_messages!' for #<#:0x007fb430638300>

how can I fix this error. Also is using Devise module good practise?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best option is to rename your own DeviseHelper to something else. Rails's autoloading is finding your implementation of DeviseHelper instead of Devise's, so the method is not being loaded. Call it something less specific, e.g. AuthHelper.

The advantage of this over pulling in your own implementation do devise_error_messages! is that you will automatically pick up changes to the method that Devise may make in future versions, as well as you'll have less code in your app, both making your code more sensible / maintainable.

Comment: thanks man, I always appreciate when someone points how to make code more friendly for other programmers and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Just add an implementation of `devise_error_messages!` to your `DeviseHelper`. You can borrow the implementation from [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Override-devise_error_messages!-for-views).

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/helpers/devise_helper.rb` file, add the `devise_error_messages!` method like this:

```
module DeviseHelper
  def devise_error_messages!
    return '' if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    html = <<-HTML
    <div class="alert alert-error alert-danger"> <button type="button"
    class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
      #{messages}
    </div>
    HTML

    html.html_safe
  end
end
```

*P.S. I already have this in one of my projects and it's working fine.*